# Selecting max value from calculated column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql select statement which goes like this:

Select a,b,calculated_column from table t1;

I come up with the calculated_column based on some logic and calculated_column is NOT a column in table t1.

How do I make this select statement return only the max value of the calculated_column?

Comment: what do you mean return the max value of the calculated column? The row that has the maximum value for calculated column?

Comment: @a.abdul Welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to use the green checkmark on the answer that helped you out the most!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a derived table:

```
SELECT MAX(calculated_column) AS MyMax
FROM 
(
    SELECT a,b,calculated_column 
    FROM   table t1;
) t2
```