# sqlalchemy SELECT column FROM (SELECT columns FROM TABLE)

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following query

```
reports = self.session.query((
        func.sum(Report.a) / func.sum(Report.b))
            .label('c'),
        Report.id,
        Report.id2
        ).group_by(Report.id, Report.id2
        )
```

I now want to get the max(c) for the reports, grouped by id.

Essentially, I am trying to have a sqlalchemy solution to this problem
[SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

but with the extra requirement that I need to calculate the value column I want to have the max in as in [Selecting max value from calculated column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475575/selecting-max-value-from-calculated-column-in-mysql)

I am finding it difficult to perform a

```
SELECT MAX(C), id FROM (SELECT A/B AS C, id FROM TABLE) t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your first query as [subquery](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery):

```py
reports = session.query(
    (func.sum(Report.a) / func.sum(Report.b)).label('c'),
    Report.id,
    Report.id2
).group_by(Report.id, Report.id2).subquery()
```

After this it can be used in another query as if it was a table:

```py
# reports.c is a shorthand for reports.columns
q = session.query(
    func.max(reports.c.c),
    reports.c.id
).group_by(reports.c.id)
```

Comment: I tried this earlier. Unfortunately, what it did was give back *every* combination of columns c and id there were. I didn't use a group_by, but the underling issue should still be there.

Comment: Well, if all _id_ values returned by subquery are unique, your result is expected. If what you really want is max value in entire result set together with its _id_, then you can sort by c in descending order and limit by 1.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is the best solution (I migrated to doing joins in python, yeah sue me), but I accepted because it might be useful for other people.